# How to print full struct path in Debug output?

Tags: struct, rust, println

I have `mymod.rs`:

```
pub mod mymod {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct mystruct {                          
        pub x: i32,
    }
}
```

And `main.rs`:

```
mod mymod;
use mymod::mymod::mystruct;
fn main() {
    let x = mystruct { x: 10 };
    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

Output is:

```
mystruct {
    x: 10,                                                    
}
```

Can I make it display the following text:

```
mymod::mymod::mystruct {
    x: 10,                                                    
}
```

?

Comment: not what you want but be aware `dbg!` exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make any changes at all to how a struct is formatted, you must manually implement `Debug` instead of using `#[derive(Debug)]`. Here's an implementation which produces the output you want:

```rust
pub mod mymod {
    use std::fmt;

    pub struct mystruct {                          
        pub x: i32,
    }
    
    impl fmt::Debug for mystruct {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
            f.debug_struct(std::any::type_name::<Self>())
                .field("x", &self.x)
                .finish()
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f688261035d78aa5e1c1cbe8323d55a8)

There might also be a library that offers an alternate derive macro for `Debug` that could be configured to print the type name this way, but I don't happen to know of one.

By the way, I notice you have `mymod::mymod`. This isn't a usual way to structure Rust code; when you write `mod mymod;`, *that itself* creates a module. The module's file should not usually contain `mod mymod { ... }` inside it; that's creating *two* levels of modules with the same name. Either use `mod mymod;` for a separate file or `mod mymod { ... }` for a module that's inline in the same file — don't use both, as it's redundant.